# DirectoryInfo & Path.GetDirectoryName - Exists method returns false while exists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to check whether a folder exists or not if not create. I'm sure this folder exists, but for some reason I get "false" when I check with "Exists" method.

The only reason I think could be because of the W: drive?
I moved this application to production site and even there it returns false.

while I'm type in Windows explorer on my localhost and on the server "W:/Webs/ASPPages/cropper/uploads" it opens this folder.  So my localhost and IIS server has W: mapping.

for test I tried to create the folder then it says can't find the path...

```
userFolderName = @"W:/Webs/ASPPages/cropper/uploads"

//I also tried @"W:\Webs\ASPPages\cropper\uploads\"

//I also tried @"W:\Webs\ASPPages\cropper\uploads" 

//I also tried "W:\\Webs\\ASPPages\\cropper\\uploads" 



DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(userFolderName);

if (dirInfo.Exists) //returns false

var diPath = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(userFolderName));

if(diPath.Exists)  //returns false
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the folder exists on the server machine, and that your app has privileges required to access it? Try Directory.Exists(). Or try testing some of the parent folders.

Comment: Yes it exists... BEcause when I copy the folder to explorer it prompts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion/experience is, that uploaded content should neither be part of your website nor should it be in your IIS websites directory. First it messes things up heavily when you have source control. The second problem is because of security, which is very restrictive for those IIS folders and so you end up in situations like the current one.

Now to the possible solution. Create the uploads folder somewhere else, on a separate drive or just another directory but make sure that it's not inside your IIS folders. Then go into IIS, select your website in the left tree control and set up a virtual directory pointing to that folder you just created. Now you probably don't need to do anything else, but if needed set up any additional rights you want to that new uploads folder and DirectoryInfo.Exists() will 99% work as expected now.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks all.. creating virtual directory and using Server.MapPath("xxx");  fixed my problem. Like that no attention needed for drive letter. thanks

Answer (score 1):

try using this in your code behind

```
userFolderName = Server.MapPath("/uploads");
```

Comment: well... this Server.MapPath only works if the "uploads" file is in the the same folder/subfolder as the application folder. In this case I need to save outside the running application folder. I logged on the IIS server as Administrator and the Application folder is W:\Webs\CNS  (the aspx page is w:\webs\cns\members\uploads.aspx\ and I need to save to W:\Webs\ASPPAges\cropper\uploads   ....

Comment: Server.MapPath is not restricted to the applications folder. If you create a folder for example W:\UploadsTest and make a virtual directory called "uploadstest" from IIS pointing to W:\UploadsTest, then Server.MapPath("uploadstest") will return "W:\UploadsTest". See my answer for more details ...

Answer (score 1):

Drive letters are mounted on a per-user or per-session (as in login session, not ASP.NET session) basis. The account under which the website is running probably doesn't have the drive letter mapped. Either use a UNC or log into the app pool account and mount the w: drive persistently.

Comment: Could you be more specific James?   When I login on IIS server I can type w:\.

Comment: Your ASP.NET application is running under an app pool. That app pool runs under an identity, such as NETWORK SERVICE, YourServer\SomeUserAccount, or YourDomain\SomeUserAccount. When you log into the server under your account, YOUR account has the W: drive mapped. The account under which the application is running would not have the W: drive mapped (unless you logged in under the same account as the app pool).